# When structuring code, where should I place object mutator?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

I know there is a Repository pattern for retreiving objects and Factory pattern for mutating objects. In case I want to modify an object, should I use another pattern or I can use Factory pattern? 
In case there is a lot of duplicate logic between Creating and Modifying, should I use a trait?

Comment: Are you talking about domain layer objects? Why would there be a lot of duplicate logic between creation and mutation? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @guillaume31 Like when you create a new Store, you need to assign a new head manager. And when you update the store you also need to assign a new manager.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the Factory pattern is not so much to mutate objects as to assemble a new entity out of multiple parts. If any invariants hold both at creation time and when you mutate the object, these should be centralized in the entity itself, not in a Factory.

As a side note, entity update operations aren't usually integral changes but partial, with intention-revealing names that reflect the ubiquitous language of your domain, e.g. `store.assignHeadManager()`, `store.startStockInventory()` etc.

Comment: what if it is possible to change as much properties as create (like an entity has 10 attributes and all those CAN(not must) be changed and when creating they all 10 have to be created) having a method inside the model might not be an ideal solution.

Comment: I’m telling you how it should ideally be done in a DDD way. Not that there aren’t exceptions or that DDD is a good fit for *your* problem. If you can’t find a good name for a single operation that can update a lot of things, just call a series of mutators. But you’re probably missing a chance of putting a name on a concept.